# f(n) is in O(g(n)), could it have same growth as g(n)?

Tags: algorithm, math, time-complexity

I know that `f(n)` grows slower than `g(n)`, but could `f(n)` has the same growth rate as `g(n)` since there is an equality sign?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the `Big-O` definition, yes. For example `n` is in `O(n)` as well. In this case, `f(n) = n` and `g(n) = n` are even equal, a stronger relation than having the same growth.